# Gradle build uses local Nexus proxy repo by default, how to make fallback to maven central faster?

Tags: gradle, build, nexus

We use a Nexus proxy for maven dependencies. This is only accessible when build is executed in our private network. Builds are run both from inside our private network and from outside.

We have configured gradle build like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
       url = uri('https://our.local.nexus/repository/maven-public/')
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**The problem:**

When build is executed outside of our private network, our.local.nexus is not accessible. It seems it takes a long time for maven to figure this out, which slows the build down a lot.

This is probably relevant:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sec:how-gradle-downloads-deps

> HTTP Retries Gradle will make several attempts to connect to a given
> repository before disabling it. If connection fails, Gradle will retry
> on certain errors which have a chance of being transient, increasing
> the amount of time waiting between each retry.

How should we modify the gradle build so that it works well for both cases: inside our local network (using our nexus proxy) and outside of local network (using maven central)?

- configure gradle somehow to fail faster when our.local.nexus is not available?
- add some kind of parameters, to tell gradle to build without our.local.nexus?

Comment: Do you have any way to detect whether you're on the local network or not?  Or, perhaps, put some value in `~/.gradle/settings.gradle`?  If so, you could wrap the `maven { ... }` in an `if( ... check for property or CLI arg ...) { maven { ... } }` and do it hat way.